# Include data from a .txt verbatim

Tags: input

I am using a finite element program that outputs data in `.txt` files. And I want to input these data in my LaTeX code. Is there a way to input the data files so that they appear as the program output format?

**Program output data file:**
[image]

**LaTeX code:**

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,openany,article]{memoir}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
    \graphicspath{{Figures/}}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\input{Data/shearwall_only_bc_A.txt}
\end{document}
```

**LaTeX output:**

[image]

Comment: Does `\verbatiminput{Data/shearwall_only_bc_A.txt}` do what you need? Requires `\usepackage{verbatim}`.

Comment: Maybe, can be also helpful the listings package...

Comment: @egreg That seems to remove all indents from the text file.

Comment: For reading the file content programmatically (e.g. to a "variable") instead, see also [filesystem access - Read file contents to variable and iterate over each character in file (hexdump) - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505849/read-file-contents-to-variable-and-iterate-over-each-character-in-file-hexdump?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In addition to [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings), the [`fancyvrb`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) package is equally suitable for this purpose.

This package provides the `\VerbatimInput` command (similar to `\verbatiminput`), which can be customised using various parameters (e.g., reducing font size).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

% redefine \VerbatimInput
\RecustomVerbatimCommand{\VerbatimInput}{VerbatimInput}%
{fontsize=\footnotesize,
 %
 frame=lines,  % top and bottom rule only
 framesep=2em, % separation between frame and text
 rulecolor=\color{Gray},
 %
 label=\fbox{\color{Black}data.txt},
 labelposition=topline,
 %
 commandchars=\|\(\), % escape character and argument delimiters for
                      % commands within the verbatim
 commentchar=*        % comment character
}

\begin{document}

\VerbatimInput{data.txt}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

**Notes:**

- specifying `|` and `(`/`)` as the escape character and argument delimiters means these symbols cannot appear as part of the verbatim text (or in this case, the contents of `data.txt`);
- the line of asterisks in `data.txt` was removed by specifying `*` as the comment character (similar to `%` in LaTeX);
- the line highlighted in green was obtained by modifying it as follows:

`(|color(Green)      8      400.519E-33      -12.      17.1429      27.3494E+03)`

Comment: To overwrite the value of previous parameters at any point, use the optional argument of `\VerbatimInput`, e.g., `\VerbatimInput[fontsize=\small]{data.txt}`.

Comment: if filename is variable then how I do that? I want to show the filename from which I load this.

Comment: @alhelal According to @nnunes you can change parameters of the verbatim input later on between the `\VerbatimInput` and the `{<filename>.txt}`. Accordingly, you can change the file name that is shown on top  with: `\VerbatimInput[ label=\fbox{\color{Black}somefilenameorganogram.txt}]{../../code/hw2/Diagrams/organogram.txt}`. (where most likely `somefilenameorganogram.txt` would just be the same as the name of the file your trying to display, i.e. `organogram.txt`.)

Answer (score 37):

Thanks to egreg.

Adding

```
\usepackage{verbatim}
```

to the preamble, and using

```
\verbatiminput{<file path>}
```

to input, does the tick!

Comment: And the font size can be controlled by just surrounding `\verbatiminput` like you normally would: `{\small  \verbatiminput}`. So this works out perfectly fine : )

Comment: After using `\usepackage{verbatim}`, I had to use the following capitalization `\VerbatimInput{<file path>}` to make it work for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can also make the font size smaller in a verbatim environment by making a new environment I call `\verbatimprog`, which uses the `\footnotesize` font size.

Place the lines below in the preamble (before `\begin{document}`):

```
 \DefineVerbatimEnvironment%
      {verbatimprog}%
      {Verbatim}%
      {fontsize=\footnotesize}%
```

Then, to use the new environment, say

```
\begin{verbatimprog}

(your program output here)

\end{verbatimprog}
```

Comment: Yes, but Malthe Eisum's question was about reading the contents of a text file automatically with a command like `\input`, and not copying the contents of the first.