# Importing separate file (literally/verbatim) into my LaTeX file

Tags: verbatim, include

I'm curious as to whether it's possible to insert an entire separate file into a LaTeX document as an inline command. For example, I have the following LaTeX code:

```
\begin{Verbatim}[frame=single]
%Want to insert all the text from another file here
\end{Verbatim}
```

So where it says %Want to insert... I'd like to insert all of the text from another file (in the same directory) into the `.tex` document so that the text in the other file appears in a box in the `.tex` document.

I hope that's clear, if not I'll clarify in the comments.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384) No need to add thanks, simply upvote any good answers you may receive.

Comment: @Decave see [**my answer**](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85218/14497) to ["how to include data from a .txt"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85200/14497). For example, to include text from file `doc.tex`, use `\VerbatimInput{doc.tex}`. Also, you may want to comment out (use `%`) the `commandchars` and `commentchar` keys until you understand what they do.

Comment: Sorry everyone, I had to leave work early today. I will test the code on Wednesday when I'm back in the office and have access to my LaTeX file.

Comment: you can `\usepackage{verbatim}` and then `\verbatiminput{frame-single}`.  (i use this all the time to include the source of a file in its own output with `\verbatiminput{\jobname.tex}`, a great way to document tests and "how to" exercises.)

Comment: On page 6 of the documentation of `fancyvrb` you find `\VerbatimInput`; I'd say that `\VerbatimInput[frame=single]{myfile.txt}` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This question is answered in the following link:

https://texfaq.org/FAQ-verbfile

Answer (score -1):

You can try the `\input` command:

```
\begin{Verbatim}[frame=single]
\input ANOTHER_FILE.tex
\end{Verbatim}
```

Comment: Have you tested your code? Witch package defines environment `Verbatim`? I suppose you will read only `\input ANOTHER_FILE.tex` instead of reading the content of the file ...