# MATLAB output into tex

Tags: matlab

Is there any way to import **raw MATLAB output** into .tex documents?

I have already seen `verbatim` package as a solution, but it does not meet my demands for 2 reasons:

1. Matrix elements are not aligned, especially when some elements have decimal digits and others don't.
2. It is not quite convenient, in case MATLAB generates a large output.

Also, I have tested `matrix2latex.m` but it seems useful only for matrices.

As I said before, it would be convenient to me if I could just import the **raw** MATLAB output into my .tex file, keeping the format as the one in MATLAB command window.

Thank you!

**Edit**: Added output generated by an .m script.

[image]

Comment: you can see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75116/what-can-i-use-to-typeset-matlab-code-in-my-document

Comment: In case I am not quite clear, I don't want to include any MATLAB code, i.e. the content of any .m file. To be more specific, I want to import only the output generated by the .m script in my .tex file.

Comment: If you use a monospaced font (like Courier) in your command window, and if you also use a monospaced font (like `\ttfamily`) in your document with a `verbatim` or similar environment, everything should line up consistently. If you're having some other problem, please construct a MWE with the smallest MATLAB output that shows the problem.

Comment: If it is only the output and you don't want them as is but in latex format, save the output as say `output.txt (or `output.dat` ,`output.csv` etc) and then use `pgfplotstable` or `csvsimple` to import them. On the other hand, you can use matlab's `publish` feature too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.txt}
A =

    0.6555    0.7060    0.2769    0.0971    0.6948    0.9502    0.4387
    0.1712    0.0318    0.0462    0.8235    0.3171    0.0344    0.3816


v =

    0.7655    0.7952    0.1869    0.4898    0.4456    0.6463    0.7094

blah blah blah
    0.7547    0.6551
    0.2760    0.1626
    0.6797    0.1190
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{verbatim} % http://ctan.org/pkg/verbatim
\begin{document}
In a simple document, the code
{\small \begin{verbatim}
A=rand(2,7), v=rand(1,7), fprintf('blah blah blah\n'); disp(rand(3,2));
\end{verbatim}}
printed the following to the screen:
% Without the verbatim package, you may need to add a \noindent between
% and after verbatim enviironments to prevent unwanted paragraph indentation.
{\small \begin{verbatim}
A =

    0.6555    0.7060    0.2769    0.0971    0.6948    0.9502    0.4387
    0.1712    0.0318    0.0462    0.8235    0.3171    0.0344    0.3816


v =

    0.7655    0.7952    0.1869    0.4898    0.4456    0.6463    0.7094

blah blah blah
    0.7547    0.6551
    0.2760    0.1626
    0.6797    0.1190
\end{verbatim}}
Alternatively, if the screen output were written to a file, and if the verbatim
package were added, it could be inserted as:
\verbatiminput{\jobname.txt}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Although I think it is useful (that's the reason I upvoted and accepted the answer), I was wondering if there is a more automated - elegant way (e.g. `\include` or sth), rather than copy - paste the data.

Comment: In that case, try [fancyvrb and verbatiminput](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85200/include-data-from-a-txt-verbatim).

Comment: Or the verbatim package. I've edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's quite late for replies, but I will like to suggest another solution:

Using the command diary in Matlab you can export all the command windows print to a specific file and later use one part of @Mike Renfro to import that txt file. I never try that, but it should do the job, and maybe more "elegant", in the meaning you dont have to write the output in the latex file.

```
%In Matlab script
diary('commandoutput.txt');    
diary on ;
enter code here you want to evaluate
diary off ;%to avoid print other commands.

%In latex file (from @Mike Renfro solution)
\verbatiminput{\jobname.txt}
```