# Caption in \lstinputlisting environment gives keyval error

Tags: input, text-decorations, text

I am trying to include the table shown in my example below (shown in the verbatim environment - but saved in a text file), but I get a keyval error stating that "Package keyval Error: $r2v$. undefined".  How can I get my caption to show up properly.

Also, how can I locally modify the text file caption to show up boxed like that shown in the accepted solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85200/include-data-from-a-txt-verbatim)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{inconsolata}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\fontfamily{zi4}\selectfont,
}
\renewcommand*{\ttdefault}{cmtt}

\begin{document}
I wanted to make the table appear like a ``programming" type text:
\begin{verbatim}
-----------------
10  1   0.3 2
20  2   0.9 5
30  3   3   8
40  4   6   9
50  5   8   10
-----------------
\end{verbatim}

\lstinputlisting[caption= Tabulated Data Showing $\theta_{1}$, $rv2$. ]{data.txt}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The arguments in ` [] ` is a comma separated list, thus the comma throws it off.  Try adding `{} ` around the caption

Comment: Hello, I tried that but it did not work.

Comment: Please update your question showing exactly what you did.

Comment: `caption={Text, text} ` should work just fine

Comment: OK, that worked.  Now, how can I get the border and boxed caption like that shown in the link? Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the basic problem was solved by comment.