# Embed .txt file, abiding to defined margins

Tags: margins, verbatim, fancyvrb

I am using this link to embed text files within my thesis.

[Include data from a .txt verbatim](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85200/include-data-from-a-txt-verbatim/85218)

Unfortunately, the contents of the text file keeps ignoring the margins. I have tried using | and (/) within my text files to return line but it doesn't work. I am using the exact code provided by **nnunes**.

[image: trxt file]

Thanks for any assistance in advance!

Comment: you have to decide what you what to do, sometimes it makes no sense to wrap verbatim content so latex doesn't but you can use `\small` or `\footnotesize` or whatever works. If you know the maximum line length that can be generated you can decide the font in advance. Or you can use an environment such as `alltt` (or `listings` with suitable options) to allow line breaks if that makes sense in your context

Comment: I just liked the styling from the linked answer and wished to use that in my thesis.

Comment: yes but most verbatim (including the tables in that answer) make no sense if you wrap the line, just put `\tiny` before the verbatim input. or whatever is needed. You have not said how wide your page is, how wide your verbatim text is so people can only give general hints not tell you exactly what font size to use.

Comment: The content of the text file consists of around 50 values, comma separated. Even with \tiny the list will go off page. Is there no method to use the margins that are already being used for the document?

Comment: yes as I say you can use `alltt` or use listings `breaklines` option or ...

Comment: but just mechanically wrapping the tables is not likely to make your thesis readable, You should also consider the option of using external tools to vertically split the data into semantically meaningful groups of columns and display them as separate tables/