# Input a file that contains special characters like "#", "_" without using external packages

Tags: macros, input, specials

**I know this is a weird and stupid question, but I really need to achieve this.** 
I have a file containing some characters like "#", "_". For example, the file is:

```
abc_def#gh
```

And I need to input (or display the file in to the pdf) to latex without using external ***packages*** like `verbatim`. Achieve this just using build in latex.

I need some kind of function to replace the special character or display it in `\verb` style without any error.

### Some limitations

- I Can't Run Bash script inside latex as well. Because of `-no-shell-escape`.
- Can't Use external packages by `\usepackage` command

Comment: under what circumstances could you input a file but not use a package? (as these are essentially the same thing)

Comment: Here is how to do it with packages [Include data from a .txt verbatim](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85200/123129). Without packages or scripts it will become unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Do you mean you want to typeset a file name or do you want to include the file contents of a file with that name (so `\input{foo_bar#baz}`)?

Comment: Why do you use the tags `verbatim` and `shell-escape`, if you don't want to use them? I removed them.

Comment: What about `\csname usepackage\endcsname{verbatim}` or `\input{verbatim.sty}`?

Comment: I really would like to know why you really need to achieve this. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to use LaTeX packages then the following solution needn't LaTeX at all. Only TeX primitives and Plain TeX basic macros are used here. But the solution works in LaTeX too, because the mentioned Plain TeX macros `\dospecials`, `\obeylines` and `\obeyspaces` are implemented in LaTeX kernel too.

```
\def\inputverbatim #1{\bgroup
  \def\do##1{\catcode`##1=12 }\dospecials
  \def\par{\endgraf\noindent\null}\obeylines\obeyspaces
  \tt \noindent
  \input{#1}
  \egroup
}

%%% test:
\inputverbatim {file.txt}
```

Comment: There's much more than `\dospecials`, `\obeyspaces` and `\obeylines` to get a working verbatim framework. Breaking ligatures, just as an example.

Comment: ligatures in `\tt` font?

Comment: I'm sure you are able to read the output of `tftopl cmtt10` to see `(LIGTABLE (LABEL O 41) (LIG O 140 O 16) (STOP) (LABEL O 77) (LIG O 140 O 17) (STOP) )` The situation is even worse when using T1 encoded fonts.

Comment: Now, 2022, somebody are using such archaic fonts?

Comment: OpenType fonts usually have much more ligatures than those two.

Comment: This depends on the configuration of text shaping routine which can be set individually for each font (so called font features). We (of course) disable ligatures for `\tt` fonts used in verbatim, so we needn't to solve this problem at macro level (which is not good place for solving such problems). You did mention a ligature ?``. This is similar obscurity like using `{\it\$}` to get £. They are features of a diluvial TeX.

Comment: The wheel has been invented millennia ago, but people continue to use it nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

It is hard to see why you could not use `\verbatiminput`

but if `myfile2` has

```
line 1
   abc_def#gh
line 3
   $$$$$$
line 5
```

then

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\edef\qqq#1{%
\noexpand\begin{verbatim}
\noexpand\input{#1}%
\@backslashchar end\string{verbatim\string}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\qqq{myfile2}

\end{document}
```

However if `verbatim.sty` is not available to be used,`article.cls` should not be available either, both are part of the core latex release. So I do not see how any latex document could work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest `listingsutf8` package and use it  like following:

> \lstinputlisting[inputencoding=utf8/cp1250,frame=hnone,numbers=none,extendedchars=true]{source.txt}

The second option is to use `\detokenize` command like

> \detokenize{abc_def\#gh}

But as you see, # must be quoted with backslash.

Comment: listings package is Ok but doesn't answer the question which (for some strange reason) asks for no packages to be used

Comment: It would be painful to achieve this without external package. At least the author can provide package files in the same directory as LaTeX source.

Comment: but you posted this after another answer which did as requested in 4 lines of code, so not that painful.

Comment: `\detokenize` appends space-tokens behind control-word-tokens, e.g., `\detokenize{\relax\relax}` yields `\relax␣\relax␣`. `\detokenize` doubles hashes/explicit character-tokens of category 6(parameter). With `\detokenize` the result depends on the value of the integer-parameter `\escapechar`. How to combine `\detokenize` with `\input`?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I might go at it:

```latex
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
% Let's create an external text file  SomeFile.tex  which is to be 
% input verbatim:
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{filecontents*}{SomeFile.tex}
Line 1: abc_def#gh
Line 2: $$$_def#gh
Line 3: %%%_def#gh

\end{verbatim}

Line 7: bla~~~bla
\end{filecontents*}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------


\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\Exchange[2]{#2#1}

\begin{document}

Text

\Exchange{\input{SomeFile.tex}}{\begin{verbatim}}\end{verbatim}

Text

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

---

If you don't wish things to be typeset in typewriter-mode and just wish TeX to treat special characters like ordinary characters that shall occur within the text while typesetting as usual, you can try s.th. like this:

```latex
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
% Let's create an external text file  SomeFile.tex  which is to be 
% input:
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{filecontents*}{SomeFile.tex}
Line 1: $&#^_~%\{}
Line 2: $&#^_~%\{}
\end{filecontents*}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable\secondwhentypesetting{\protected\def\secondwhentypesetting#1#2{#2}}
\newcommand\unexpandedwhennottypesetting[1]{\noexpand\unexpandedwhennottypesetting{\unexpanded{#1}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\myactivateasnospecial{\@dblarg\@myactivateasnospecial}%
\newcommand\@myactivateasnospecial[2][]{%
  \begingroup\lccode`\~=`#2\relax
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\secondwhentypesetting\unexpandedwhennottypesetting{#1}}%
  \catcode`#2=13\relax
}%
\makeatother

\DeclareRobustCommand\TypesetFileWithSpecialsAsOrdinaryCharacters[1]{%
  \begingroup
  % switch special characters %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \let\do=\myactivateasnospecial
  \do\$%
  \do\&%
  \do\#%
  \do[\ifmmode\hat{}\else\textasciicircum\fi]\^%
  \do[\ifmmode\_\else\textunderscore\fi]\_%
  \do[\ifmmode\sim\else\textasciitilde\fi]\~%
  \do\%%
  \do[\csname\ifmmode\else text\fi backslash\endcsname]\\%
  \do\{%
  \do\}%
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \input{#1}%
  \endgroup
}%

\begin{document}

\TypesetFileWithSpecialsAsOrdinaryCharacters{SomeFile.tex}

$$\TypesetFileWithSpecialsAsOrdinaryCharacters{SomeFile.tex}$$

\end{document}
```

[image]